# How to reload only visible (last) cells of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am building a chat application. I use `UTableView` to construct chat box. When I load chat box screen, I need to scroll tableview to the index path of last unread message. I am using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method to do so. In this case, `cellForRowIndexPath` is called for all the cell's from indexPath 0. This badly affects application performance. Since I am using automatic dimension for cell height, I won't be able to use `setContentOffset` method also.

Is there any other way to scroll tableview to required indexPath without loading intermediate cells?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways you can achieve desired behavior.

1. Using scrollToRowAtIndexPath with **animated** = false
2. Using **setContentOffset** method with calculated height. This will require actually calculate cell's height.